# Is apache spark 3.0.1 vulnerable cause of CVE-2020-27216?

Tags: apache-spark

We are getting following vulnerability in our security scan, for apache spark.

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-27216

spark-core_2.12-3.0.1.jar (shaded: org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.4.18.v20190429)

Can't exclude and include the latest jetty jars, as spark is using it as shaded jar. Also did not found the same vulnerability mentioned in anywhere for apache spark. Following are the links i checked.

https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-38954/Apache-Spark.html
https://spark.apache.org/security.html

Want to know if this is false alarm for spark or spark implemented the workaround for this. ??

**Update:**

Get to know, Spark is not doing unpacking of any web app. Hence issue is not present in Spark. But using vulnerable jar is not a good idea, hence spark is updating the jar version in upcoming release. Spark ticket for jar upgrade. issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33831

Thanks

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi my team is using spark too and we are facing a lot of cve, may I know how do you resolve them?

Comment: Hi @weikangchia ... sorry was not much active on stack-overflow. saw your post today. we usually update to the latest spark, and run in k8s environment. Also excluding the jar  which is not required at all(Big list). by doing this gettign minimal cve which is not applicable to our app.